# Moq: Mocking an interface of abstract base class of a controller

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting, moq

My problem:
I want to unittest a controller. This controller has a constructor that includes a repository. Repositories are named like `SomethingRepository`. `SomethingRepository` inherits from abstract class `BaseRepository<ReadModel, Dto, Filter>`. `BaseRepository` inherits from interface `IRepository<ReadModel, Dto, Filter>`.

When I want to mock `SomethingRepository` using Moq, I will need to mock the interface, as far as I understand, since mocking a class will demand an empty constructor which `SomethingRepository` and `BaseRepository` don't have. (I don't want to add one)

So, I have tried

```
Mock.Of<
   IRepository<
       SomeReadModel,
       SomeDto,
       SomeFilter>
>();
```

However, when I try to assign this mock (with a cast) to a variable of type `SomethingRepository`, I get an `InvalidCastException`:

> System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'Castle.Proxies.IRepository`3Proxy' to type 'Repositories.SomeRepository'.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What's the exact type of the parameter the controller receives?

Comment: You are doing it wrong, a mock of Interface cannot be assigned to a Class inheriting from it. They are different types. and cannot be assigned to each other. If you need to pass the abstract class as repository, mock the abstract class, not the interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor of `SomeController` has the following signature which takes in an `IRepository`:

```
public SomeController(IRepository<ReadModel, Dto, Filter> repository)
    : base(repository)
```

In my test, I was trying to do cast this to the concrete repository:

```
SomeRepository repository = (SomeRepository) Mock.of<IRepository<ReadModel, Dto, Filter>>;

new SomeController(repository);
```

Instead, I need to pass the repository interface into the controller, not the concrete class:

```
IRepository<Something> repository = Mock.of<IRepository<ReadModel, Dto, Filter>>;

new SomeController(repository);
```

Answer (score 3):

Every `SomeRepository` is a `IRepository<SomeReadModel, SomeDto, SomeFilter>`, but not every `IRepository<SomeReadModel, SomeDto, SomeFilter>` is a `SomeRepository`. If your controller injects a `SomeRepository`, you have to provide something which is (or inherits from) the `SomeRepository` class.

The solution is to change your controller so that it injects a `IRepository<SomeReadModel, SomeDto, SomeFilter>` instead.